# How to call 2 different modules with different URL. server keep sending first modules results for the second request

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to nodeJS. I'm trying to call 2 different modules with separate  URL requests but server keep sending the first module's JSON array, how can i solve this problem.

here is the app.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const bearModeule = require('./bear');
const batModule = require('./bat');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/',bearModeule);
app.use('/bat',batModule);


const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listing on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Bear module code

```
let bear = function(req,res,next){

    let bearArray = [
        {id:1, name:"polar bear"},
        {id:2, name:"grizzly bear"},
        {id:3, name:"panda bear"}
    ]

    res.send(bearArray);
    next();
}

module.exports = bear;
```

Bat module code

```
let bat = function(req,res,next){

    let batArray = [
        {id:1, name:"black bat"},
        {id:2, name:"brown bat"}
    ]

    res.send(batArray);
    next();
}

module.exports = bat;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply in app.js write the following code.

```
const express = require('express');
const bearModeule = require('./bear');
const batModule = require('./bat');
const router = express.Router(); 
const app = express();

app.use('/', router);

app.get('/bear', bearModeule);
app.get('/bat', batModule);

const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(`Listing on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`app.use()` to specify middleware as the callback function

The problem what I think is the definitions of the modules (bear and bat), Modules should handle the routing on there ends, Use the express.Router class to create modular, mountable route handlers.

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    let bearArray = [
        {id:1, name:"polar bear"},
        {id:2, name:"grizzly bear"},
        {id:3, name:"panda bear"}
    ]

    res.send(bearArray);
})

module.exports = router
```

and

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use(function timeLog (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: ', Date.now())
  next()
})
// define the home page route
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    let batArray = [
        {id:1, name:"black bat"},
        {id:2, name:"brown bat"}
    ]

    res.send(batArray);
})

module.exports = router
```

https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Thanks a lot mastermind there is a routing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your code here :

```
app.use('/',bearModeule); // this means return bearModeule for all requests at localhost:3000
app.use('/bat',batModule); // this means return batModule for all requests at localhost:3000/bat
```

app.use() defines a middleware to be used when the respective route matches. When you hit localhost:3000/bat, the bearModeule request is fired. You can see that the console prints an error that headers can not be set after they are sent. This is because your requested route has already returned the response.

You should give a different route for bear module.

```
app.use('/bear', bearModeule)
```

Or if you want to return the batModule first you can change the order of routes.

```
app.use('/bat',batModule);
app.use('/', bearModeule);
```

This will work but it's still not the right way to do it.
Also you should use app.get if you want to define it as an endpoint.